# React/Firebase. Why I can't update data in my Firestore Database?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Why I can't  update my data? I created a function, but when I want to change the data in my `Firestore Database`, when I click on the button, the following error occurs in the console  `FirebaseError: No document to update: projects/star-one-web-120f0/databases/(default)/documents/users/YVZ8kOtWSuOJJqlHqPVqnTOvl803`. What am I doing wrong?

This is update function with `state` and `UserAuth` context:

```
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [phone, setPhone] = useState('')
    const [language, setLanguage] = useState('')
    const [valute, setValute] = useState('')
    const [instagram, setInstagram] = useState('')
    const [name, setName] = useState('')



    const {user} = UserAuth()

    const updatePerson = async(email) => {
        await updateDoc(doc(db, 'users', user.uid), {email})
    }
    
    const updatePersonData = async() => {
        await updatePerson(email)
    }

      <input type="text" placeholder={user.displayName || user.email || user.phoneNumber} className='form-control' onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}/>
     <input type="text" placeholder={instagram} className='form-control' onChange={(e) => setInstagram(e.target.value)}/>
     <input type="text" placeholder={email} className='form-control' onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
     <input type="text" placeholder={phone} className='form-control' onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)}/>
     <input type="text" placeholder={language} className='form-control' onChange={(e) => setLanguage(e.target.value)}/>
     <input type="text" placeholder={valute} className='form-control' onChange={(e) => setValute(e.target.value)}/>

    <button className="btn events1 btn-white" onClick={updatePersonData}>SAVE</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message already says what you are doing wrong. The user you want to update doesn't exist.

The User with the id `YVZ8kOtWSuOJJqlHqPVqnTOvl803` doesn't exists in your `users` collection in the Firestore.

If you want to update an actual document in the `Firestore Database` make sure  `user.uid` points to an existing document in your `users` collection. Alternatively the document exists but the collection doesn't and the document is placed in a different collection.

If you want to update the Authentification Email the user uses to signin you have to use another function:

```js
import { updateEmail, getAuth } = 'firebase/auth';

const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);

const updatePerson = async (email) => {
    await updateEmail(auth.currentUser, email)
}
```

**Edit (depending on the comments below):**
In order to keep your document ID in sync with the ID of the user in the Firebase Authentication you have to create the `users` document with the ID you get in return after creating the Auth User.

```
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, setDoc } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseApp = // your firebase app obj
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    const user = userCredential.user;
    const uid = user.uid;
    setDoc(doc(db, 'users', uid), {
        // the data you want to store in your document
    });
    // now the document will have the same ID as the auth user
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    // ..
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I need to change other data besides an email. Email resulted only for an example. How to change other fields besides an email? I did not think that there is such a function `updateEmail`. I added other `inputs` and `state`. Please, check it out

Comment: Also, when I am trying to use your solution only with `email` I am getting this error `FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/network-request-failed).`

Comment: The question is: do you create a user document inside a `users collection` in your firestore?

Comment: Yes, inside a `users collection`  is storing the data of each registered user

Comment: Can you verify that there is a document `YVZ8kOtWSuOJJqlHqPVqnTOvl803` inside the users collection?

Comment: Nope, I don't see this object. I assume that they have different `IDs`

Comment: In my `Firestore Database` this document displays with this `ID`: `JhXlRDzyV7HFM0xrPYTy` and when I am calling a function `updatePersonData`  the response happens to another `ID`:`YVZ8kOtWSuOJJqlHqPVqnTOvl803 `. But how to make this document have the same `IDs`?

Comment: Wait i'll edit my answer in a second.

Comment: Please check my edit of my answer, this should fix your problem